# File length is different in Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader.getResource()

Tags: java, unit-testing, scala

I tried to measure the file length in unit test and ran into issue. What could possibly make this test fail?

```
val fileName = "filetypes/b.jpg"
val root = "C:/Users/Zotov/Work/project/target/test-classes/"
val lenAbsolute = new File(root + fileName).length()
val lenResource = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader
  .getResource(fileName).getFile.length()
assertEquals(lenAbsolute, lenResource)
```

value of lenAbsolute is the one reported by filesystem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
.... .getResource(fileName).getFile.length()
```

The `ClassLoader.getResource()` method returns a `URL`.

The `URL.getFile()` method returns a `String`.

The `String.length()` method returns the length of the string ...